# using nawk, how to sum all numbers in $1, $2, and $3 fields?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Using nawk, how to sum all numbers in `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` fields?

```
8     6     2

7     3     5

1     9     4
```

I want the result to be sum = 45

Comment: I had a comment, realized the question was across all.  Can it be a bash script or do you want a one-liner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nawk 'BEGIN { sum=0; } {sum += $1 + $2 + $3;} END { printf "%d\n", sum } ' a.in`

Answer (score 5):

using  awk:

```
awk '{x+=$0;}END{print x}' RS="[ \n]"  file
```

This will work irrespective of the number of rows or columns. By using the record separator(RS) as space or a newline, every value is split into a separate line, and hence can be easily added.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with coreutils and bc:

```
<file head -c-1 | tr ' \n' '++'; echo) | bc
```

If some columns should be omitted, e.g. if the input is like this:

```
A 8 6 2
B 7 3 5
C 1 9 4
```

`cut` can select the wanted ones:

```
<file cut -d' ' -f2- | head -c-1 | tr ' \n' '++'; echo) | bc
```

Output in both cases:

```
45
```